# CKEditor conflicting with TextAngular

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, textangular

We have a nifty AngularJS 1 app and we're using TextAngular add on. Works great. We now have the requirement to add the customer's custom header into our work, which is being added via JS AJAX call and it inserts the HTML into the page. This header is using CKEditor. I've asked to remove it but they can't. As a result, when I click into my TextAngular box, the CKEditor toolbar appears.

Thoughts on how I can separate the two? It appears CKEditor is attaching itself to any div where contenteditable="true". Is there a way to tell CKEditor to ignore divs?